# How to migrate an Android 2.2 application to higher versions

Tags: android

I have developed on Android application using sdk 2.2. Is it possible to migrate my application to higher version without re-coding. If yes, please let me know the procedure.

Comment: You don't have to recode to migrate on upper version

Comment: ya but you can change your sdk version Rightclick on your project -> Properties -> Android (You will see projec built target) select any on from it it will change your project sdk

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to recode it.

Just change in `manifest file` as,

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14"
/>
```

Comment: I would say it's better to check if your code doesn't use any depreciated methods before changing `targetSdkVersion` to higher.

Comment: If I mention target sdk as 14, will my application run on other higher versions?

Comment: Without looking at code, i can't tell you exactly. But, if your are not using any `deprecated method` in your code, then it will run for sure.. :)

Comment: Its a big project. I can't copy the code here. As you said, I have changed the target sdk version. But in the project structure, it is showing the Android 2.2 jar file. How can I use the features which are introduced in the later versions.

Comment: Right Click on your Project `Click on Properties->Android->Select Your Versions(From List of SDK's)->Click apply->click OK` it will automatically create your new `jar`